# How to add a button and text over image when hovering (HMTML/CSS/Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am able to display two span text elements over the image when I hover over with my cursor successfully. But I am having trouble placing a button that is centered over the image, below the project name. Any help would be appreciated. I should also note the button that I want to use is from a Bootstrap 3 class.

**Here is a demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/oo1xx006/3/

Here is an example of what I want to create: http://www.devonstank.com/

HTML:

```
<div class="latest_projects">
<!-- My latest projects -->
  <h1>My latest projects</h1>
  <br>
  <ul class="projects-list">
    <li>
      <img src="img/mudmat-global-model.jpg" alt="DOF Mudmat Lowering" width="380px" height="380px"/>
      <span class="text-content">
          <span class="project-type"><i>Project Type</i></span>
          <span class="project-name">Project Name</span>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-default project-name" role="button"><span>View project</span></a> -->
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <a href="portfolio" class="btn btn-default" role="button">View more projects</a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
}

h1 {
/*  margin: 15px 0;*/
    font-size: 1.9em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 120%;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

p {
    line-height: 200%;
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.btn-default:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 2px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}    


/************************************
HOME
************************************/

.latest_projects {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.latest_projects p {
    margin: 0;
    color: transparent;
}

.fluid-container img {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}



/*******Project Images******/    

ul.projects-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.projects-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 380px;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 380px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 380px;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 380px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 380px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.projects-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 380px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 380px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.project-type {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: 25px 0;*/
    padding: 120px;
    width: 380px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.7em;
}

span.project-name {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

span.view-project {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: 25px 0;*/
    padding: 10px;
    width: 380px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Javascript. Basically you have a container, inside which you need to see/use extra content if you hover on it. I suggest that you should add the needed html, but with `display: none;` CSS rule, and then you need to show it when the user hovers the container and hide it if the use leaves the container. This is how you can do it with jQuery:

```
$(".yourcontainerclass").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".yourinnerclass").hide();
});

$(".yourcontainerclass").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".yourinnerclass").show();
});
```

Comment: I don't want to edit it just to fix a typo, but `displaz: none` should be `display:none`. Also, have a look at [Paul Irish on why show() and hide() cause a huge performance hit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88#issuecomment-72400007)

Comment: @DanielF, thank you for pointing out the typo. Usually I have a class called invisible and add/remove it when I need to do that, but here I wanted to simplify things,as if we go deep into the details, then a beginner will not understand the answer.

Comment: That make sense. I expected that you were simplifying, I just wanted to make sure that if someone else reads the question later they will be able to see the drawbacks